# working with folder and file operations (move, add, rename, delete) in vim is not as comfortable as gui editior

Tags: user-interface, vim, nerdtree

I am using vim for last 8 month and I think I am better in editing code and switching among files compared to my GUI editor but only thing I could not improve is file and folder operations I am always switching to VSCode for these operations

for example, let's say if I use VSCode I can simply drag and drop to move files and folders, right click and rename or create new It's very convenient

In vim ( NerdTree) if I want to move a file or folder with `m` It sends me to line editor where vim binding doesn't work ( movement with arrow keys is frustrating ) and creating renaming files and folders is also not easy as GUI editor

Is there something I am missing or this problem is because of mixing the philosophy of GUI editor and vim? maybe there is some better way to do this in vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something I am missing

Yes, the fact that you should use your desktop environment's file explorer to perform directory/file operations and not *a text editor*.

Use a specialized tool for editing text (like Vim) and other specialized tools for other tasks.